# How can I compute the movement of an object along a parabola?

Tags: 2d, physics, geometry

I am working on a simple 2D game. In the game, I have a 'robot' that throws a ball towards another robot, in the shape of a parabola. Both 'robots' have the same Y coordinate.

The program knows the positions of the two robots, and it knows the position of the parabola's apex ('vertex') as shown here:

[image]

I need the ball to travel along the parabola. This means (correct me if I'm wrong), that at any given time, I need to be able to calculate the Y position of the ball, since I know it's X position.

If so, how can I calculate that Y position at any given time, knowing the information above. Please try to make your answers as clear as possible, since my math knowledge is very basic.

Comment: Are you looking for the Angle and Power to throw at? Or the Velocities in X and Y to throw at?

Comment: Also, can you be more specific about what "Vertex" is, is it always the top of the curve, or will it be on the side sometimes?

Comment: @MickLH It's always the top of the curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're looking for a parabolic function *y(x)* that equals zero at two known points. Let's call those points *r<sub>1</sub>* and *r<sub>2</sub>*, after robots 1 and 2. One solution is easily found:

*y(x) = ( x - r<sub>1</sub> )( x - r<sub>2</sub> )*

On top of the robots, one of the terms in parentheses becomes zero, which, multiplied by something else, remains zero. For that reason, we can multiply the entire thing by a factor *a*. This stretches the parabola vertically (or flips it upside down for negative values) without changing the location of the zeroes. We manipulate *a* to make sure the curve passes through the vertex, defined by coordinates *(x<sub>v</sub>, y<sub>v</sub>)*. We solve the following equation for *a*:

*y(x<sub>v</sub>) = y<sub>v</sub>*

*a ( x<sub>v</sub> - r<sub>1</sub> )( x<sub>v</sub> - r<sub>2</sub> ) = y<sub>v</sub>*

This yields:

*a = y<sub>v</sub> / (( x<sub>v</sub> - r<sub>1</sub> )( x<sub>v</sub> - r<sub>2</sub> ))*

We get the function *y(x)* we want by multiplying our original function with the scaling factor *a* we just obtained:

*y(x) = ( x - r<sub>1</sub> )( x - r<sub>2</sub> ) y<sub>v</sub> / (( x<sub>v</sub> - r<sub>1</sub> )( x<sub>v</sub> - r<sub>2</sub> ))*

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about projectiles here, and you know the X position, though it can simply be calculated:

[image]

Where *d* is the horizontal distance from the launch point.

You can simply calculate the y at distance x this equation:

[image]

Where:

- x is the x position.
- theta is the angle with the ground.
- g is the gravity constant.
- v is the velocity .